# Double Linked List gets error 'pointer being freed was not allocated'

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor, doubly-linked-list

I created a double linked list class, and am trying to use it with a Vector class I created, in order to make a vector of linked lists, however at the end of the program it seems I am getting an error 
`malloc: *** error for object 0x100100be0: pointer being freed was not allocated`
which I am assuming has to do with the destructor, also that is where Xcode is pointing me to. How do I circumvent this? I think my destructor works fine, however I guess I am wrong.

Test File:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Vector.h"
#include "doubleLL.h"

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    Vector<double_llist<string> > listWords(27);
    double_llist<string> numbers;
    numbers.push_back("one");
    numbers.push_back("two");
    numbers.push_back("three");
    listWords[0] = numbers;
    listWords[0].print();
}
```

doubleLL.h:

```
#ifndef DOUBLELL_H
#define DOUBLELL_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class double_llist {
private:
    struct node {
        T data;
        node* prev;
        node* next;
        node(T t, node* p, node* n) : data(t), prev(p), next(n) {}
        int count;
    };
    node* head;
    node* tail;

public:
    double_llist() : head( NULL ), tail ( NULL ) {}
    template<int N>
    double_llist( T (&arr) [N]) : head( NULL ), tail ( NULL )
    {
        for( int i(0); i != N; ++i)
            push_back(arr[i]);
    }
    bool empty() const { return ( !head || !tail ); }
    operator bool() const { return !empty(); } 
    void push_back(T);
    void push_front(T);
    T pop_back();
    void removeNode(node *);
    void print();

    node* search(T data) {
        node *tempNode;
        if (head == NULL) {
            // List is empty
            return NULL;
        } else {
            tempNode = head;
            while (tempNode != NULL) {
                if (tempNode->data == data) {
                    tempNode->count += 1;
                    if (tempNode->count >= 4) {
                        // Push tempNode to front of linked list
                        push_front(tempNode->data);
                        head->count = tempNode->count;
                        removeNode(tempNode);
                    }
                    return tempNode;
                } else {
                    tempNode = tempNode->next;
                }
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    ~double_llist()
    {
        while(head)
        {
            node *temp(head);
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }

    double_llist& operator = ( const double_llist& other )
    {
        if (this == &other) {
            return *this;
        }
        while (!empty()) {
            pop_back();
        }
        for (node *itr = other.head->next; itr != other.tail; ++itr) {
            tail = new node(other.head->data, itr, NULL);
        }
        return *this;

    }


    double_llist(const double_llist& other)
    {
        head = new node;
        tail = new node;
        head->tail = tail;
        tail->prev = head;
        *this = other;
    }
};

template <class T>
void double_llist<T>::push_back(T data)
{
    tail = new node(data, tail, NULL);
    if( tail->prev )
        tail->prev->next = tail;

    if( empty() )
        head = tail;
}

template <class T>
void double_llist<T>::push_front(T data) {
    head = new node(data, NULL, head);
    if( head->next )
        head->next->prev = head;

    if( empty() )
        tail = head;
}


template <class T>
T double_llist<T>::pop_back()
{
    node* temp(tail);
    T data( tail->data );
    tail = tail->prev ;

    if( tail )
        tail->next = NULL;
    else
        head = NULL ;

    delete temp;
    return data;
}

template <class T>
void double_llist<T>::removeNode(node *n) {
    if(n == this->head) {
        this->head=this->head->next;
        this->head->prev = NULL;
    } else if (n==this->tail) {
        this->tail=this->tail->prev;
        this->tail->next = NULL ;
    } else {
        n->prev->next = n->next;
        n->next->prev = n->prev;
    }
}

template <class T>
void double_llist<T>::print() {
    node* temp;
    temp = this->head;
    int i = 0;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if (i < 3) {
            cout << temp->data << endl;
            temp=temp->next;
            ++i;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    return;
}

#endif
```

The error seems to be coming from doubleLL, so Vector.h was not included. If it is needed to help point me in the right direction, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: step through this with a debugger, it's too complex to determine by looking at the code..

Comment: I have been for some hours now, I have tried Malloc to no avail, it prints out the one, two, three, however it crashes at the end.

Comment: @Muller have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes I did, but after thinking it over for a few minutes, in that copy constructer, isn't that just NULLing out the list and nothing else?

Comment: @Muller that should work, I tested it and it did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not obeying the rule of 3: `If you have either of a destructor, a copy constructor or an assignment operator implemented, you should implement all three.` I stepped through your code and there appear to be a lot of object copies created and then destroyed, but since copying is not done properly, already destroyed memory is being deleted again.

Properly implement these and the problem will be no more.

EDIT:

I just finished a basic implementation of those:

```
double_llist& operator = ( const double_llist& other )
{
   head = NULL;
   tail = NULL;
   return *this;
}
double_llist(const double_llist& other)
{
   head = NULL;
   tail = NULL;
}
```

The code no longer crashes.

SECOND EDIT:

```
double_llist& operator = ( const double_llist& other )
{
   head = NULL;
   tail = NULL;
   node* otherNode = other.head;
   while ( otherNode )
   {
  push_back(otherNode->data);
  if ( otherNode == other.tail )
     break;
  otherNode = otherNode->next;
   }
   return *this;
}
double_llist(const double_llist& other)
{
   head = NULL;
   tail = NULL;
   node* otherNode = other.head;
   while ( otherNode )
   {
  push_back(otherNode->data);
  if ( otherNode == other.tail )
     break;
  otherNode = otherNode->next;
   }
}
```

Comment: +1. I was about to post that. Rule of Three if C++03, or Rule of Five if C++11.

Comment: I see how you did that, however when I use them, there is no longer any output from the Vector of double linked list. I thought on the third line under public, that was the copy constructor?

Comment: @Muller No, third line under public is a constructor that takes an array. Lucian's code snippet shows the right signature. BTW, his copy constructor is not copying anything, so you'll need to implement it yourself (perhaps by doing a deep copy). Same goes for the assignment operator: Lucian's code leaves the target blank, you need to write an implementation for it.

Comment: @Muller that's a basic implementation, you'll have to the the actual implementation yourself.

Comment: @Muller - That line copies elements from an array into the list, but it is not a "copy constructor" which has a very specific meaning, namely that it copies an object of the type into the object (of same type) that is being constructed.

Comment: This is what I thought, I was wondering how he got it typed up so fast ;) 

I'll get started there, and hopefully will report back with a correct answer.

Comment: @Muller great, I'm pretty sure that is the cause, but you can never know until you actually try it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I did any attempt, and added it to the OP, however I don't think I have done it right as I am not getting anything.

Comment: Also, try to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: why are the head and tail set to NULL at the beginning of the functions?

Comment: @Muller so they're not un-initialized in case of copying from an empty list.